# How to simplify the following R code for writing many CSV files?

Tags: r

I would like to output the following data in a list in R, I would like to keep the original colnames, I do know how to simplify it, I think `lapply()` does not work.

```
write.csv(weekly_data$NO_2005_2011_all_site,'Weekly_NO_2005_2011_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$NO_2017_2021_all_site,'Weekly_NO_2017_2021_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$NO2_2005_2011_all_site,'Weekly_NO2_2005_2011_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$NO2_2017_2021_all_site,'Weekly_NO2_2017_2021_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$NOx_2005_2011_all_site,'Weekly_NOx_2005_2011_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$NOx_2017_2021_all_site,'Weekly_NOx_2017_2021_all_site',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$O3_2005_2011_all_site,'Weekly_O3_2005_2011_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$O3_2017_2021_all_site,'Weekly_O3_2017_2021_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$PM10_2005_2011_all_site,'Weekly_PM10_2005_2011_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$PM10_2017_2021_all_site,'Weekly_PM10_2017_2021_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$PM2.5_2005_2011_all_site,'Weekly_PM2.5_2005_2011_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$PM2.5_2017_2021_all_site,'Weekly_PM2.5_2017_2021_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$SO2_2005_2011_all_site,'Weekly_SO2_2005_2011_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(weekly_data$SO2_2017_2021_all_site,'Weekly_SO2_2017_2021_all_site.csv',row.names = FALSE)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, I know Loop could work, I would like to know is there any other method could finish it, thank you.

Comment: It's more complicated than just writing a `for()` loop. One must evaluate the data frame name and column names in a way that not only produces the correct data in each CSV file, but the file names and the column names for the vectors in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent a minimal reproducible example in the original post, here is an example of how to write the columns from the `mtcars` data frame to column specific CSV files.

The basic logic is that once we know the data frame name and its columns, we can use the column names to drive an `lapply()` function to extract each column into a data frame via a combination of the `get()` function and the `[` form of the extract operator.

We cast the result as a data frame so we can set the column name to something other than `x`.

```
# use mtcars data as an example
theColumns <- colnames(mtcars)
outputDirectory <- "./data/mtcarsExample/"
if(!dir.exists(outputDirectory)) dir.create(outputDirectory)
lapply(theColumns,function(x,y){
     df <- data.frame(get(y)[,x])
     colnames(df) <- x
     write.csv(df,paste0(outputDirectory,x,".csv"),row.names = FALSE)
     paste(paste0(outputDirectory,x,".csv"),"written to disk")
},"mtcars")
```

As the `lapply()` function works its way through the columns in the data frame, it writes the file names to the output list.

[image]

...and the output for the first file, `mtcars$am` looks like this when viewed in Microsoft Excel:

[image]